# filtering pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

If I have the following DataFrame:

```
Name    Total    Category
 A       150         c1         
 A        92         c2
 A        13         c9
 A         4         c8
 B       100         c8
 B        12         c7
 B        10         c5
 C       410         c2
 C       222         c1
 C        33         c4
 C        24         c9
```

How can I filter the above DataFrame using the following rules:
For each distinct **Name**, return the two rows with the lowest **Total**.

In the case of the example above, I want to get this:

```
Name    Total    Category
 A        13         c9
 A         4         c8
 B        12         c7
 B        10         c5
 C        33         c4
 C        24         c9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
In [247]: df.sort_values(['Name','Total']).groupby('Name').head(2)
Out[247]:
   Name  Total Category
3     A      4       c8
2     A     13       c9
6     B     10       c5
5     B     12       c7
10    C     24       c9
9     C     33       c4
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solutions with [`SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest.html):

Get all indices of smallest values of group by [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html), because get `MultiIndex` and need select second level and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['Total'].nsmallest(2).index.get_level_values(1)])
   Name  Total Category
3     A      4       c8
2     A     13       c9
6     B     10       c5
5     B     12       c7
10    C     24       c9
9     C     33       c4
```

Solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), but then is necessary reorder columns:

```
df = df.set_index('Category').groupby('Name')['Total'].nsmallest(2).reset_index()
df = df[['Name','Total','Category']]
print (df)
  Name  Total Category
0    A      4       c8
1    A     13       c9
2    B     10       c5
3    B     12       c7
4    C     24       c9
5    C     33       c4
```

**Timings**:

```
#len(df) = 60k
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [92]: %timeit (df.set_index('Category').groupby('Name')['Total'].nsmallest(2).reset_index())
100 loops, best of 3: 19.2 ms per loop

In [93]: %timeit (df.sort_values(['Name','Total']).groupby('Name').head(2))
10 loops, best of 3: 27.5 ms per loop
```

---

```
#len(df)=600k
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [104]: %timeit (df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['Total'].nsmallest(2).index.get_level_values(1)])
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop

In [96]: %timeit (df.set_index('Category').groupby('Name')['Total'].nsmallest(2).reset_index())
10 loops, best of 3: 162 ms per loop

In [97]: %timeit (df.set_index('Category').groupby('Name')['Total'].nsmallest(2).reset_index()[['Name','Total','Category']])
10 loops, best of 3: 161 ms per loop

In [98]: %timeit (df.sort_values(['Name','Total']).groupby('Name').head(2))
1 loop, best of 3: 351 ms per loop
```

Comment: It's an interesting solution +1. Can you add some timing too?

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Comment: My solution is fatser, see timings.

Comment: can you add timing for your original solution too?

Comment: Really interesting, it is the fastest. ;)